# How to protect picam flex cable?

Tags: cable, picam

i was wondering if it may be usefull to have a protection for the flex cable of the picam.

My picam will work in really dusty area. I can't find any hardware protection for this cable (or maybe i don't need it).

Has anyone ever protected their picam flex cable ? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard cable I have is coated on both sides it does not need anything over it.

The issues you will get from dust are:

- The camera lens gets covered and does not focus / twist so easily
- The USB and Ethernet ports get clogged
- The camera and screen connector get clogged
- The HDMI ports get clogged
- The SD card gets gritty when removed / inserted

After time, the chips on the board get hotter as the layers of dust settles on them or in any heat spreaders / fans you have.

Two cures:

1. Regular maintenance with a can of air - let the Pi cool down first as the air [gets cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law) very quick and you want to avoid [thermal shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_shock). Not that I have ever broken an adapter card from this...
2. Use a good case - [IP5x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code) rated or above

The issue with the cases though are:

- Heat build up - fitting a filtered fan helps and good filters over the air entry / exit points
- Paths for cables

There was a kickstarter for a bird watching Pi case that was great but I've not been able to track on down for sales for months but the most extreme way is to [put the Pi in mineral oil](http://thomasloughlin.com/raspberry-pi-in-mineral-oil/) but I think that's a bit overkill to keep the dust away :)

**tldr;
 - No the cable will be fine
 - Keep the dust off the Pi and camera with regular maintenance**